# Converting XML to C# object

Tags: c#, xml

I need to get the OrderID from these xml data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2015-12-10T16:12:55.184Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>967</Version>
  <Build>e967_core_Bundled_5642307_R1</Build>
  <OrderArray>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>865826</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Active</OrderStatus>
   </Order>
  </OrderArray>
</GetOrdersResponse>
```

I have tried this one but does not work.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlResult);
var orderElements = xDoc.Elements("GetOrdersResponse").Elements("OrderArray").Elements("Order");
foreach (XElement elem in orderElements)
{
    var orderId = Convert.ToInt32(_xmlHelper.GetChildElementValue(elem, "OrderID"));
}
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such problem, i would always choose using XmlSerializer. 
Use this classes:

```
    using System;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    namespace classes
    {
        [XmlType(Namespace = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents")]
   public class Order
    {
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType(Namespace = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents")]
    public class OrderArray
    {
        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents")]
    public class GetOrdersResponse
    {
        public string Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string Ack { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string Build { get; set; }
        public OrderArray OrderArray { get; set; }
    }

    }
```

Then Deserialize to your object:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GetOrdersResponse ));
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlResult))
{
    GetOrdersResponse result = (GetOrdersResponse) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}

int id=result.OrderArray.Orders.First().OrderID; //this will return ID of first object in Orders list.
```

Comment: "        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
        public string Xmlns { get; set; }" looks very very wrong... and most of those should be XmlType, not XmlRoot

Comment: fyi it is still far more complex than it needs to be - `XmlSerializer` makes a lot of reasonable assumptions, such as "namespaces are inherited by children" and "things are elements named like the member" - so all you need is: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/1b91e0e5e6a47bdb3cff42e61281f6ce - purely FYI

Comment: heh, sorry, but I love your answer (I like `XmlSerializer`), but if we assume that `OrderArray` is actually 0-1-or-many, you an also lose an entire type (`OrderArray`) and just use `public List<Order> OrderArray { get; set; }` on the `GetOrdersResponse`

Comment: Thats right, but one given example it was not necessary. But this should be implemented, otherwise OrderArray would be redundant.

Comment: Finally, if you use `public int OrderID { get; set; }`, the correct conversions will happen automatically

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("YourXMLFile");
var orderId = xdoc.Descendants("OrderID").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't expect `xDoc.Elements("GetOrdersResponse")` to work, because that is looking in the default namespace, where-as everything here is in `"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"`. As such, you'd need *at a minimum* to tell it that via `XName`:

```
    var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlResult);
    XNamespace ns = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents";
    var orderElements = xDoc.Elements(ns + "GetOrdersResponse")
            .Elements(ns + "OrderArray").Elements(ns + "Order");
    foreach (XElement elem in orderElements)
    {
        var orderId = (int)elem.Element(ns + "OrderID");
    }
```

(note the use of `(int)` to do xml-specific casting, too)

However, it may be easier to just use `XmlSerializer` and let *it* worry about unscrambling the data.

Answer (score 1):

You should be use this sample code

Importent Note

- Serialized class mark as `[Serializable]` attirbute
- If the class name   is not same as the xml root tag, class will be
  mark as    `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "XmlTagName")]` attribute
- If serialized class    have property type as another class, this
  property mark as    [`XmlElement("XmlTagName")]` attribute

> Sample Code

**Model**

```
      [Serializable]
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "HardwareInfo")]
        public class Hardware
        {
            [XmlElement]
            public string cpu_name { get; set; }
            [XmlElement]
            public int ram_size { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("hard_disk")]
            public List<HardDisk> hd { get; set; }                   
        }

        [Serializable]
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "hard_disk")]
        public class HardDisk
        {
            [XmlElement]
            public string model { get; set; }
            [XmlElement]
            public string size { get; set; }
        }

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xmlString = @"<HardwareInfo>
                                  <cpu_name> ABC Pentium xyz</cpu_name>
                                  <ram_size> 123 </ram_size>
                                  <hard_disk>
                                    <model>Toshiba XYZ</model>
                                    <size> 123 GB </size>
                                  </hard_disk>
                                  <hard_disk>
                                    <model>Logitech XYZ</model>
                                    <size> 99 GB </size>
                                  </hard_disk>
                                </HardwareInfo>";

            var result = DeSerialization<Hardware>(xmlString);
        }

        static T DeSerialization<T>(string xmlStrig) where T : class
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));                        
            using (StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xmlStrig))
            {
                return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sReader);
            }
        }
    }          
}
```

Comment: sorry, but this is just ... unhelpful; `XmlSerializer` does **not** care about `[Serializable]` - at all. The main complicating factor in the question is *namespaces*, which this answer doesn't address; and: it isn't even remotely specific to the question...

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using `XmlDocument` and `XmlNodeList` also - if you are saving the xml data in file

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("your XML File Name with extension");
        XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("OrderID");
        for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(elemList[i].InnerText);
        }
```

Comment: This will work, but `GetElementsByTagName` is almost always a terrible solution to any problem - hugely prone to errors etc. The primary complication in the question is namespaces, which can be tackled perfectly fine via the regular query methods of both `XDocument` and `XmlDocument`, without needing the nuclear option of `GetElementsByTagName`