# C# XML Deserialization of unknown nodes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I'm very new to .NET, I need to Serialize an XML to object.
How can I write `Field.cs` so that it can be serialized for the following XML?

```
<root>
  <field name="title">
    <value>Title 1</value>
  </field>
  <field name="body">
    <value>
      <div>
        Nested HTML markups with all possible elements.
        <p> A para here</p>
        <a href="#">A link here</a>
        <section>any possible html elements</section>
      </div>
    </value>
  </field>
</root>
```

Here's what i've done so far:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "field")]
public class Field
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

This only serialized first item(title). So how can I define Value property so that it can contain anything?

P.S. I do not need to access `div`, `p`,`a` etc as objects inside `Field` object. Rather anything inside `<value>` be stored as `string` would be just fine.

---

I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47721542/2559864) I was looking for.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "field")]
public class Field
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "value")]
    public Value Value { get; set; }

}
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "value")]
public class Value
{
    [XmlAnyElement]
    [XmlText]
    public XmlNode[] Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: please check this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109646/converting-xml-to-c-sharp-object/43109813#43109813

Comment: Hüseyin BurakKaradag, I can't find anything over there. There's straight one to one mapping between nodes and properties.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [C# Get all text from xml node including xml markup using Visual studio generated class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40715261/3744182) and [How to get an XML node value as string when deserializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47719672/3744182).

Comment: Demo of the solution from [C# Get all text from xml node including xml markup using Visual studio generated class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40715261/3744182): https://dotnetfiddle.net/5i01Uc